# how to use stored procedure in Linux command prompt

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I want to alter the stored procedure in my server machine.I am uploading the codes via SSH Linux command prompt,i need to alter an existing stored procedure in my server.I don't have c- panel or php Myadmin access.I have to update it via command prompt.

stored procudere:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `dbname`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_data`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_data`(
    f_id INT(11), 
    f_guild_parentid INT(11),OUT lastid INT
    )
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO zid_tabename
         (
         id,
         character_detail_id,
         media_id,
         )
         VALUES 
         ( 
         f_id,
         f_character_detail_id,
         f_media_id,
         NOW() ,
         NOW() 
          );
          SET lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I need command to perform this.Can any one give me the command with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place that script in a file and run it via mysql command line from any server from which access for the user you want to run as is allowed.

```
mysql -h {hostname} -u {username} -p{password} {database} < /path/to/script
```

Obviously you must have the mysql client package installed on the server your are running from.

Comment: Database name is not mentioned in answer,how it will place the script in database.

Comment: @user2681579 Yes. You would need to keep that in. And I updated the answer to reflect DB naming. I simply left that part out.

Comment: we can use "mysql> source /path/to/text_file.sql" also